# Re-running chart.js with different variable

Tags: ajax, chart.js

On page load my code generates a bar chart via AJAX request:

```html
function docharts(name) {   
 $.ajax({
        url: "sql/getdata.php",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            staff: name,
        },
        success: function(data) {

            **code to assign labels etc**

        var ctx = document.getElementById("summary").getContext("2d");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                 showTooltips: true,
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata,            

                });
        myChart.update();        
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
};
```

This works as expected. However I want to be able to re-run this function with a different variable ("name") and for it to redraw the chart based on this new data.

When I run `docharts("foobar")` the graph **does** redraw with the new data, however when the cursor is dragged back outside the canvas it appears to redraw the original graph.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instead of declaring the variable in your ajax request, declare it beforehand and check if there is an active chart and destroy that first then your behaviour will go away.

```js
var chart = null;

const addChart = (chartConfig) => {
  if (chart) chart.destroy();

  var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
  chart = new Chart(ctx, chartConfig);

  chart.update(); 
}
```

Working sample:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var options2 = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var chart = null; // DECLARE BEFOREHAND

var option1 = true;

const addChart = (chartConfig) => {
  if (chart) chart.destroy(); // DESTROY CHART IF EXISTS

  var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
  chart = new Chart(ctx, chartConfig);

  chart.update();
  option1 = !option1;
}

document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener("click", () => {
  option1 ? addChart(options) : addChart(options2);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="myButton">
Gen Chart
</button>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/6gf0hs9q/19/